# Socket.io Java Client with support for 1.0.x

Tags: java, javascript, android, socket.io

I am writing an Android app that connects to a server using socket.io (v1.0.4). Is there a socket.io Java client out there that works with socket.io v1.0?

I was originally using the [Gottox solution](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) but [it only seems to work with socket.io <= v0.92](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/issues/100).

Some other libraries available

- https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync
- https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java

[nkzawa's](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java) claims to be supported for 1.0 but there seem to be some [issues with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386302/java-implementation-for-client-socket-io-compatible-with-version-1-0).

Comment: This could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386302/java-implementation-for-client-socket-io-compatible-with-version-1-0

Comment: sure it is. but is a good question. For the time of the other, doesn't have answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got [nkzawa's solution](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java) working on my server running socket.io v1.0.6. If you aren't using Maven you have to install quite a few dependencies.

I answered this question's duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24988407/2426888).