# socket.io and java - connection failure

Tags: java, node.js, socket.io

I cannot connect to my node.js server from java using socket.io-java-client from [gottox](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client). I followed the build recommendation for socket.io v. 1.0.6 from beenjaminn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386302/java-implementation-for-client-socket-io-compatible-with-version-1-0/24988407#24988407).

Here is my connect command:

```
socket.connect("http://192.168.1.7:8000/", this);
```

Here is the resulting error:

```
an Error occured
io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
    at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:323)
    at io.socket.IOConnection.access$7(IOConnection.java:293)
    at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:200)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for     
URL: http://192.168.1.7:8000/socket.io/1/player
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:314)
    ... 2 more
Jul 03, 2015 11:08:38 AM io.socket.IOConnection cleanup
INFO: Cleanup
```

From javascript using the socket.io npm module I can connect fine.

```
var socket = io("http://" + location.host + "/player", {reconnection: false});
```

Note that the javascript client first requests an html page from 192.168.1.7:8000 which downloads the js above which then makes the websocket connection in the line above.

What is wrong with my java client connection?

Comment: returned HTTP response code: 400 , sound like bad request http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this [alternate implementation](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java) for the java client from nkzawa.  It worked right out of the box.